# How to easily parse an array from an INI file to an array in C?

Tags: c, parsing, ini

In my code I use the iniparser (https://github.com/ndevilla/iniparser) to parse double, int and strings. However, I'm interested into parsing arrays, delimited with comma such as

```
arr = val1, val2, ..., valn
```

Any easy and quick way, like the parser above?

Comment: Just parse them as double, int, strings etc and add them to an array.

Comment: C doesn't really have general-purpose arrays, so you'll need to invent your own structure to represent these in a meaningful form.

Comment: @tadman He is not asking about putting different types in the same array.

Comment: @Fredrik -- the OP _might_ be asking about putting different types in the same array. It isn't clear (to me, at least) what types `val1`, etc., are. They might be the same type, or they might not. In any event, it will probably necessary to create some sort of data structure to represent a variable length array, whatever types it contains, as C doesn't really have any built-in support for this.

Comment: @Fredrik It's not about the types, it's that in C arrays do not have an integral size component. There's no way of saying "some arbitrary number of `int` values" in C without a custom struct.

Comment: @tadman you know the size when you parse then you can use VLA or just use malloc instead of an array.

Comment: @Fredrik Sure, but how do you preserve the length of this thing? That's why I say you need a custom structure to store it. All the other ones are just a plain type.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make your own structure.
You can find easily on the web structures that you can import for your code. Another solution, not so great is to put your values as void pointers. And when you want to take your values back you take the void pointer and cast it with which kind of value you want( int,double,char ect). But this may conflict the values so you must be careful. You must know what kind value is in which cell of the pointer. It is not the ideal way but its a cheat way to avoid making your own structure.

Comment: He is not asking about putting different types in the same array.

Comment: Although it lacks some detail, this is broadly the right answer. If you want to model a complex data structure (and it doesn't have to be _very_ complex) in C, you get to write, or obtain, some code to do it. The OP alread found something to handle the basic parsing, but it isn't clever enough for the new job. So the choices come down to (1) extend it, (2) write a new one, or (3) find a better one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libconfini](https://github.com/madmurphy/libconfini), which has array support.

test.conf:

```ini
arr = val1, val2, ..., valn
```

test.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <confini.h>

struct my_conf_T {
    size_t arrlen;
    char ** arr;
};

static int my_listnr (IniDispatch * this, void * v_conf) {
    #define conf ((struct my_conf_T *) v_conf)
    if (ini_string_match_si("arr", this->data, this->format)) {
        conf->arrlen = ini_array_get_length(this->value, INI_COMMA, this->format);
        if (!conf->arrlen || !this->v_len) {
            /*  Array is empty  */
            return 0;
        }
        conf->arr = (char **) malloc(conf->arrlen * sizeof(char *) + this->v_len + 1);
        if (!conf->arr) {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        char * remnant = (char *) ((char **) conf->arr + conf->arrlen);
        memcpy(remnant, this->value, this->v_len + 1);
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < conf->arrlen; idx++) {
            conf->arr[idx] = ini_array_release(&remnant, INI_COMMA, this->format);
            ini_string_parse(conf->arr[idx], this->format);
        }
    }
    return 0;
    #undef conf
}

int main () {
    struct my_conf_T my_conf = (struct my_conf_T) { 0 };
    if (load_ini_path("test.conf", INI_DEFAULT_FORMAT, NULL, my_listnr, &my_conf)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Sorry, something went wrong :-(\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (my_conf.arr) {
        /*  Do something with `my_conf.arr`...  */
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < my_conf.arrlen; idx++) {
            printf("arr[%zu] = %s\n", idx, my_conf.arr[idx]);
        }
        free(my_conf.arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
arr[0] = val1
arr[1] = val2
arr[2] = ...
arr[3] = valn
```

P.S. I happen to be the author.